# database search page using universal sentence encoder for simantic search

Tags: javascript, php, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, sentence-similarity

im trying to build a page that uses uneversal sentence encoder modle to search through database 'abstract' attribute and this error is appearing in the browser console [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rIUW.png)
i first stored all data in an array and then tried to encode each one and compare to a search word 'encryption'

this is the php page code :

```
<?php

 $dbhost = "localhost";
 $dbuser = "root";
 $dbpass = "";
 $db = "portal";
 $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db) or die("Connect failed: %s\n". $conn -> error);
 // Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
  echo "Connected successfully";
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT abstract FROM projects";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $abstracts = array();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result ) > 0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $abstracts[] = $row;

        }
    }
   print_r($abstracts);
    
    ?>
   
   <script>const dotProduct = (vector1, vector2) => {
  return vector1.reduce((product, current, index) => {
    product+= current * vector2[index];
    return product;
  }, 0);
};

// square each value in the array and add them all up, then square root.
const vectorMagnitude = (vector) => {
  return Math.sqrt(vector.reduce((sum, current) => {
    sum += current *  current;
    return sum;
  }, 0));
};

const cosineSimilarity = (vector1, vector2) => {
  return dotProduct(vector1, vector2) / (vectorMagnitude(vector1) * vectorMagnitude(vector2));
};
(async () => {
    // download the model
    const model = await use.load();
    const abstracts = <?php echo json_encode($abstracts); ?>;
    const userQuery = "encryption";
    // embed the user input and the blog posts using the model -  explained next!
    const abstractsTensor = await model.embed(abstracts);
    // wrap the user input in an array so model can work with it
    const userInputTensor = await model.embed([userQuery]);

    // == New code starts here //v,mv dijv
    // convert to JS arrays from the tensors
    const inputVector = await userInputTensor.array();
    const dataVector = await abstractsTensor.array();
    
    // this is an array of arrays, we only care about one piece of user input, one search query so
    const userQueryVector = inputVector[0];

    // how many results do i want to show
    const MAX_RESULTS = 2;
    // loop through the blog  post data
    const predictions = dataVector.map((dataEntry, dataEntryIndex) => {
        // COSINE SIMILARITY - compare the user input tensor with each blog post.
        const similarity = cosineSimilarity(userQueryVector, dataEntry);
        return {
          similarity,
          result: abstracts[dataEntryIndex]
        }
        // sort descending
      }).sort((a, b) => b.similarity - a.similarity).slice(0, MAX_RESULTS);
    
    document.querySelector("#initial-example-results").innerText = JSON.stringify(predictions, null, 2)
  })();</script>
    <p>This will take a few moments for the model to load and run. Query: "encryption"</p>
<pre id="initial-example-results"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

abstract is an array contains this values :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW0wE.png)

i cant tell what the error is

Comment: Can you also post what `$abstracts` looks like?

Comment: @FiddlingAway i updated the question with the content of $abstract , please if you can help me with it i have to submit this assignment by thr end of the week

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/semantic_similarity_with_tf_hub_universal_encoder#similarity_visualized), in order to get something like this:

[image: example image showing results of sentence level meaning similarity analysis]

you would need to change your array.

Instead of having it like this:

```
$abstracts = [
    [
        "abstract" => "Cyber security is the practice of defending computers, servers, mobile devices, electronic systems, networks, and data from malicious attacks. It's also known as information technology security or electronic information security. The term applies in a variety of contexts, from business to mobile computing, and can be divided into a few common categories. "
    ],
    [
        "abstract" => "Data mining is the process of fmding anomalies, patterns and correlations within large data sets to predict outcomes. Using a broad range of techniques, you can use this information to increase revenues, cut costs, improve customer relationships, reduce risks and more."
    ],
    [
        "abstract" => "A network consists of two or more computers that are linked in order to share resources (such as printers and CDs), exchange files, or allow electronic communications. The computers on a network may be linked through cables, telephone lines, radio waves, satellites, or infrared light beams."
    ]
];

$abstracts = json_encode($abstracts);

/*
output:

[
    {
        "abstract":"Cyber security is the practice of defending computers, servers, mobile devices, electronic systems, networks, and data from malicious attacks. It's also known as information technology security or electronic information security. The term applies in a variety of contexts, from business to mobile computing, and can be divided into a few common categories. "
    },
    {
        "abstract":"Data mining is the process of fmding anomalies, patterns and correlations within large data sets to predict outcomes. Using a broad range of techniques, you can use this information to increase revenues, cut costs, improve customer relationships, reduce risks and more."
    },
    {
        "abstract":"A network consists of two or more computers that are linked in order to share resources (such as printers and CDs), exchange files, or allow electronic communications. The computers on a network may be linked through cables, telephone lines, radio waves, satellites, or infrared light beams."
    }
]

*/
```

it needs to look like this:

```
$abstracts = [
    "Cyber security is the practice of defending computers, servers, mobile devices, electronic systems, networks, and data from malicious attacks. It's also known as information technology security or electronic information security. The term applies in a variety of contexts, from business to mobile computing, and can be divided into a few common categories.",
    "Data mining is the process of fmding anomalies, patterns and correlations within large data sets to predict outcomes. Using a broad range of techniques, you can use this information to increase revenues, cut costs, improve customer relationships, reduce risks and more.",
    "A network consists of two or more computers that are linked in order to share resources (such as printers and CDs), exchange files, or allow electronic communications. The computers on a network may be linked through cables, telephone lines, radio waves, satellites, or infrared light beams."
];

echo json_encode($absctracts,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); // the switch / flag isn't a must, but it's a good idea to handle cases like non-standard characters, or emojis

/*
output:

[
    "Cyber security is the practice of defending computers, servers, mobile devices, electronic systems, networks, and data from malicious attacks. It's also known as information technology security or electronic information security. The term applies in a variety of contexts, from business to mobile computing, and can be divided into a few common categories.",
    "Data mining is the process of fmding anomalies, patterns and correlations within large data sets to predict outcomes. Using a broad range of techniques, you can use this information to increase revenues, cut costs, improve customer relationships, reduce risks and more.",
    "A network consists of two or more computers that are linked in order to share resources (such as printers and CDs), exchange files, or allow electronic communications. The computers on a network may be linked through cables, telephone lines, radio waves, satellites, or infrared light beams."
]
```

This change will make your `const abstracts` a regular string array, which is what the `model.embed(...)` expects - take a look at how you're defining the `userInputTensor` variable. You're wrapping a string ('encryption') within brackets, turning it into a one dimensional string array. It makes sense to do the same thing when defining `const abstracts`.

Bottom line - change the way you're filling the `$abstracts` array. Make it a simple array with numerical indices / indexes, instead of associative one:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT abstract FROM projects";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $abstracts = array();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result ) > 0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $abstracts[] = $row["abstract"]; // <== this is what you need to change

        }
    }
?>
```